# Results in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Table A:

```
Id|name
1 |John
2 |Tom
3 |Max
4 |Paul
```

Table B:

```
Id|item|user
1 |100 | 3
2 |100 | 1
```

With Laravel, how can I collect just the users that are not present in table B?

Comment: Isn't **Table A `id` == Table B `user`** ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the relationship as `HasMany`

```
$tables = TableA::doesnthave('users')->get();
```

With this, You will get only those records which `user` does not have value in `TableB`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TableA extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TableB','user','id');
    }
}
```